# How do I incorporate Go into an existing project?

Tags: go

I have an existing project, and I am attempting to add a new Go-based component to it. However, I am having trouble figuring out a directory structure that is amenable to Go and also fits in with the existing structure.

Here is my current project structure (simplified):

```
content
└── (some other stuff is in here)
db
└── (some other stuff is in here)
Makefile
server
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
├── options.go
├── routes.go
└── server.go
```

All components of the project are in subdirectories from the main one, and each component has a target in the Makefile to build it. So in this case, I would like to be able to run `make serve` and have Go build, and then run, the server. (Note that I am *not* trying to use Make as a Go build system — it is merely a task runner. When you have many projects, having a common language-independent set of commands such as `make serve` is useful).

Here are the things I have tried so far:

1. Keeping the Go files immediately inside the `server` directory (so `server/server.go`, `server/routes.go`, etc, as is pictured above), and having the Make task run `cd server; go build .`. This successfully builds and runs the server. However, any compilation errors will start with `./server.go:`, rather than `server/server.go:`, so I lose the ability to control-click on a filename in my terminal to open the offending line in my editor. I'm accustomed to writing code like this and I'd really like to keep doing it.
2. Keping the Go files inside the `server` directory (as above), and having the Make task run `go build server`. This gives me the error `package server is not in GOROOT`. Which, to be fair, it isn't, but I don't think putting it in `GOROOT` is the right thing to do.
3. Avoiding Go modules entirely, setting `GOPATH` to `$(pwd)/server`, putting the Go files in `server/src/my-server`, and running `go build`. This gives me the error `go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory`, which I thought was strange, as I was trying to opt out of modules. (I learnt Go after modules were added and it's hard to find documentation on how do things without them; I'm still a little confused by this.)
4. As above, putting the Go files in `server/src/myserver`, setting `GOROOT` to `$(pwd)/server`. This gives me all kinds of errors such as `package errors is not in GOROOT`. Again, to be fair, it's not, but I have no idea how to solve that issue.

I *cannot* do the thing that Go seems to *want* me to do, which is to have the entirety of my Go code all inside one directory — this is a Go component of an existing project, not a project completely written in Go. Nor do I want to have to go into the `server` directory in order to do anything Go-related, because none of the other components in any other project have that requirement.

Is there any way for me to get the hierarchy I want with Go?

Comment: Have you tried `go build server/*` (or something like that) instead of `go build server` (which will assume `server` is a package, accessible through the environment, rather than a directory just withing pwd)?

Comment: @mkopriva: Thanks for the suggestion, it works great! I have to have `go.mod` and `go.sum` outside the directory still, but that's such a small thing compared to being able to control-click. Thanks again.

Comment: Try `go build -modfile server/go.mod server/*` or `go build -modfile=./server/go.mod server/*`

Comment: If that don't work try looking at https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Compile_packages_and_dependencies it may contain some solution for you.

Comment: That nets me `cannot find main module, but -modfile was set` but I'll keep plugging away. I'm already a lot closer than I was when I started.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about Go wanting you to have everything all in one directory. In Go, directories correspond to packages, and you can certainly have multiple packages in a project.

Comment: what is the content of `db` & `content` folder,
is it also go code?

Comment: @AltianoGerung: `db` is a bunch of SQL, and `content` is a bunch of HTML with a Ruby script to do a little bit of post-processing/linting to the files before they get served.

Comment: @HymnsForDisco: Ah, I meant to say that Go wants me (with `GOPATH`) to have everything _rooted_ in one directory, with multiple packages existing somewhere in that directory's hierarchy, not that Go wants me to put every single Go file I have in one folder with no nesting. (Upon re-reading my question, I can see how that's not clear)

Comment: You will benefit from learning about modules. `GOPATH` mode is the old way, and disabled by default since 1.16 https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules

Comment: I think you should move on with it,
and have a different strategy to prevent `go build` error in the first place,
just `go vet .` everytime you done develop something.
I know it's not answering the question tho.